# Initial step for Creating a web application in Asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could you advice a basic step for creating a web application using c#?
I am confused about how to use it, since I don't know how to write an event for a button, etc.
I also don't know the difference between an input button and an asp.net button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are a beginner, this is what you should watch to get a quick intro. http://www.asp.net/general/videos/building-web-applications-with-aspnet-35-and-microsoft-visual-web-developer-2008

There are a lot of other videos here as well.

Answer (score 3):

Go to [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net).